# How to use DataBindingUtil with an Android spinner?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the new Android data binding library and get the following error trying to populate a spinner with the selected value.

Error Message (during compilation in Android Studio):

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>     ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:selection' with parameter type java.lang.String. file:/Users/ove/Code/AndroidStudio/Samples/Receipts/app/src/main/res/layout/dialogfragment_inputamount_db.xml loc:40:29 - 40:44 ****\ data binding error ****

My layout file looks the following (not complete):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="receipt"
            type="com.example.model.Receipt" />
    </data>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/currency"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:entries="@array/currency_array"
        app:selection="@{receipt.currency}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Anyone out there that has managed to get data binding to work with spinners?

Ove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a class BindingUtils and paste setSelection method

```
public class BindingUtils
  {
       @BindingAdapter({"bind:selection"})
       public static void setSelection(Spinner spinner, int position)
       {
            spinner.setSelection(position);
       }
  }
```

inside spinner

```
app:selection="@{receipt.currencyIdx}"
```

Thats all you have to do.

Comment: This will work for one way binding, how about two way binding?? selecting an item in the spinner updates the model.

Answer (score 1):

The setter [`Spinner:setSelection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int)) inherited from `AbsSpinner` has `int` parameter - not `String`:

`public void setSelection(int position)`

you should pass a position, not the value of the selection

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/currency"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:entries="@array/currency_array"
    app:selection="@{receipt.currencyIdx}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How to pass dynamic string array to the entries attributes, i.e. fetching data from the server and putting in array string and then want to populate it on spinner. so how we can do that using databinding?