# how to 2 way bind spinner selected value to value in arraylist

Tags: android, android-databinding

I managed to bind spinner to `ArrayList` of `objects`, now I need to make it that when you select certain item from spinner that it reflects to `ViewModel` (*setter gets called and sets value of a variable to what selected index is in spinner*)

I managed to make it work the other way around, value from `viewmodel` is reflected to `view` ( *like this [How to use DataBindingUtil with an Android spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996263/how-to-use-databindingutil-with-an-android-spinner)* ).

relevant xml

```
<data>
<variable
            name="spinnerList"
            type="com.example.root.proj.viewmodels.MonumentTypeVMList"/>
</data>


<Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            bind:spinnerbind="@{spinnerList.list}"
            bind:selection="@{spinnerList.selection}"
            ></Spinner>
```

custom binding

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:selection")
public static void bindSelection(Spinner spinner, int position) {
    spinner.setSelection(position);
}
```

Comment: can you share model/pojo class?

Answer (score 10):

An even simpler (to my mind) solution is presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042222/spinner-2-way-databinding), the key being the use of the [selectedItemPostion attribute of the Spinner](https://github.com/asatyana/Spinner2WayDataBinding/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L27) which is not in the code included with the question but is in the repo that it links to:

`android:selectedItemPosition="@={model.position}"`

I used the above approach successfully. This does require doing the mapping from position to actual spinner list items but I needed to do that for my use case anyway.

Comment: why does that give unknown attribute warning

Comment: because AS doesn't have great databinding integration yet. And that particular point is a fairly difficult problem, because AS needs to validate a layout file post annotation processor, which is of course difficult.

Answer (score 9):

Pretty much the same as Ajit's answer but using android:entries instead of binding an adapter.

```
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/typeSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@{vehicle.types}"
                    android:selectedItemPosition="@={vehicle.selectedTypePosition}">
```

Then my observable class

```
    @InverseBindingMethods({
        @InverseBindingMethod(type = AppCompatSpinner.class, attribute = "android:selectedItemPosition"),
    })
    class Vehicle extends BaseObservable {

    String[] types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.service_types);

    String type = null;

    @Bindable
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.type);
    }

    Integer selectedTypePosition = 0;

    @Bindable
    public Integer getSelectedTypePosition() {
        return selectedTypePosition;
    }

    public void setSelectedTypePosition(Integer selectedTypePosition) {
        this.selectedTypePosition = selectedTypePosition;
        type = types[selectedTypePosition];

    }

    @BindingAdapter("selectedItemPositionAttrChanged")
    void setSelectedItemPositionListener(AppCompatSpinner view, final InverseBindingListener selectedItemPositionChange) {
        if (selectedItemPositionChange == null) {
            view.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        } else {
            view.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectedItemPositionChange.onChange();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "selectedItemPosition")
    Integer getSelectedItemPosition(AppCompatSpinner spinner) {
        return spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

}
```

Simplified this from my implementation and didn't test it. Should work though...

Comment: I have getting error as : Error:(43, 10) error: @BindingAdapter on invalid element: setSelectedItemPositionListener(android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner,android.databinding.InverseBindingListener)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Inverse Binding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingListener.html) to achieve this. You will need to define two custom bindings.

1. To get the latest value from the spinner and set in the model.
2. Trigger an event when a new value is selected in the spinner.

To get the selected value from the spinner add this method to your custom bindings.

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "selection", event = "selectionAttrChanged")
  public static String getSelectedValue(AdapterView view) {
    return (String) view.getSelectedItem();
  }
```

To trigger an event when new value is selected in the spinner use

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"selection", "selectionAttrChanged", "adapter"}, requireAll = false)
  public static void setAdapter(AdapterView view, String newSelection, final InverseBindingListener bindingListener, ArrayAdapter adapter) {
    view.setAdapter(adapter);
    view.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        bindingListener.onChange();
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //Nothing
      }
    });
    if (newSelection != null) {
      int pos = ((ArrayAdapter) view.getAdapter()).getPosition(newSelection);
      view.setSelection(pos);
    }
  }
```

Now in your layout file just use the above binding as:

```
<Spinner
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:adapter="@{AdapterFactory.getAdapter(context)}"
      app:selection="@={model.selectedValue}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement two way binding for Spinner

1) Use custom attribute and add two way binding expression to bind property of data model to the custom attribute, in the below code, bind:paymentMode is custom attribute.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    . . .
    bind:pmtOpt="@={accountSettings.defaultPaymentOption}"
    app:adapter="@{spinAdapter}" />
```

2) Then to provide the behavior or setter method that needs to be used when data binding (data model to spinner) occurs for this attribute, BindingAdapter needs to be defined. When binding occurs, we need to set the default selected value and add item selected listener to spinner and in the listener when item select event occurs, we need to inform data binding framework to capture the value by using InverseBindingListener to initiate inverse binding.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"bind:paymentMode",
"bind:paymentModeAttrChanged"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setPaymentMode(final AppCompatSpinner spinner,
        final String selectedPmtMode,
        final InverseBindingListener changeListener) {
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            changeListener.onChange();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            changeListener.onChange();
        }
    });

    spinner.setSelection(getIndexOfItem(spinner, selectedPmtMode));

}
```

3) Define inverse binding adapter (spinner to data model) which is used by framework to capture the user selected value and set it to data model. This gets called when InverseBindingListener gets notification.

```
   @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "bind:paymentMode",
            event = "bind:paymentModeAttrChanged")
    public static String getPaymentMode(final AppCompatSpinner spinner) {
         return (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
    }
```

For more information about data binding and spinner two way binding implementation refer to 
http://www.zoftino.com/android-data-binding-library-tutorial