# Spinner 2 way databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I am not able to get 2way databinding to work with spinner. I exported my android studio project here - https://github.com/asatyana/Spinner2WayDataBinding

Appreciate experts help

Here is my activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="myModel"
            type="com.example.spinner.model.SpinnerModel" />
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.spinner.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@{myModel.countries}"
            app:selection="@{myModel.countryIdx}"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/spinner"
            android:text="@{myModel.country}" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

My Model

```
public class SpinnerModel extends BaseObservable{

    private String [] countries;
    private int countryIdx;
    private String country;


    public SpinnerModel()
    {
        List<String> allCountries = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (String countryCode : locales) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

            allCountries.add(obj.getDisplayCountry());

        }

        countries = allCountries.toArray(new String[allCountries.size()]);
    }

    public String[] getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(String[] countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public int getCountryIdx() {
        return countryIdx;
    }

    public void setCountryIdx(int countryIdx) {
        this.countryIdx = countryIdx;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return countries[countryIdx];
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'll say more: there was a (simple) fix to the BindingAdapter that affected spinners, but the fix is only defaulted in later versions of Android Studio 2.2.

Comment: Still on 2.1 as this is the latest stable. Let me try upgrading to 2.2 BETA.

Comment: I am using same approach for the problem 2 way data binding for spinner and i found there is warning on selectedItemPosition . Why that so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a typo in adapters used in AS 2.1. You can work around it:

```
@InverseBindingMethods({
  @InverseBindingMethod(type = Spinner.class, attribute = “android:selectedItemPosition”),
})
```

You can apply this annotation to any class in your project.

Comment: I got @InverseBindingMethods not applicable to method with AS 2.1.3

Comment: Because it's should be applied to class, not method.

Comment: Thanks a lot George, I was able to get it to work. Updated the github with my example.